# Java MultiThreading communication, Producer-Consumer-Cancellation, four threads interacting. Any clean robust way to do it

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, race-condition

[image: Logic Flow A, Processing a New Batch order, Involving 3 threads]

*Logic Flow A, Processing a New Batch order, Involving 3 threads*

[image: Logic Flow B, Cancelling a Batch Order, 1 thread]

*Logic Flow B, Cancelling a Batch Order, 1 thread*

**Scenario**

1. We have a BatchOrder of goods that will need to be broken down into individual ItemOrders to be processed
2. At any point of time, a Cancel request for a BatchOrder may arrive

**Implementation**

1. I have implemented some code but then I feel the pseudo code laid out in above tables are in fact much more concise and hopefully clearer
2. Logic Flow A, Processing a New Batch order, Involving 3 threads
3. Logic Flow B, Cancelling a Batch Order, 1 thread

**Requirement**

1. Cancellation should be accurate and complete for ItemOrders that has not entered the 'Filling' status state
2. Cancellation should be efficient -- it should stop any unnecessary creation and processing of ItemOrders whose BatchOrder is cancelled, and has not entered the 'Filling' state, as early as possible.
3. ItemOrder that has entered 'Filling' state can not be cancelled by the system but manually

**Questions**

1. if Step c_2, c_3, c_4 happens before pb_5, there will be outstanding 'orphan' ItemOrders that are meant to be cancelled. how to prevent this, considering Requirement 1 and 2.
2. since Step c_5 can happen at anytime, is the mechanism I have set up in the pseudo code adequate to address Requirement 1 and 2?
3. In general, is there any generic design pattern we can abstract to handle this kind of situation since I think this is a pretty generic MultiThread scenario applicable to many systems (almost all the online shopping cart system, for one)? we can see it as a Producer/Consumer scenario with an addition of 'ProducerCancelHandler', no?

[UPDATE]

**Answers**

for Question 1, one possible solution may be

- the Cancel thread will raise volatile 'cancelSignalReceived' flag in BatchOrder
- the Batch process thread will check the 'cancelSignalReceived', at the end of each loop, and raise another volatile flag 'terminatedDueToCancelSignal' (without it, ItemOrder[i] may not be completely 'set up' hence not put in the Batch order by the Batch process thread, so the Cancel thread won't be able to find it, but then the Batch process thread will finish its loop and 'set up' this ItemOrder - by this it becomes an 'orphan' ItemOrder that supposed to be cancelled but not marked as 'cancelled')
- the Cancel thread will spin and wait until 'terminatedDueToCancelSignal' is true, then proceed to do cancellation actions

But OMG, I can't help thinking: why does this typical scenario require this kind of intricate/hairy/clumsy solution? i.e. back to my Question 3, shouldn't there be some pattern we can abstract and follow in this situation, something much more elegant, simplistic and robust?

Comment: Your title says "four threads interacting" but I don't see any attempt to describe how they interact.  If the threads are doing IO, you pretty much must use an `interrupt` to cancel, otherwise the IO will just block.  So you're probably reduced to checking `isInterrupted` everywhere.

Comment: If you have multiple threads mutating shared state, then the overall design should be questioned.

Comment: Queues are a common abstraction for coordinating threads and a poison pill to stop a consumer. If you think in higher-level abstractions you might get cleaner code (less coupled) at a small cost (lower performance and more code).

Comment: @Michael, could you give some advice how I can re-design for my specific case (which is not a special or uncommon case, as I mentioned) so that I can eliminate or drastically reduce the need of any mutating shared state? I would really appreciate, truly.

Comment: @BenManes I believe, poison pill, at least the conventional one, is put in the queue by the producer when it doesn't have any more to produce, in which case, still just two threads are involved. In my case, there is a 'cancel' signal and what we want to 'poison' and kill is some specific target in the queue. hence I am not so sure how this 'pattern' will help me to achieve the Requirement 1 and 2 more effectively. any thoughts?

Comment: In that case you would clear the queue and place 1 pill per consumer inside of it, thereby halting each when they fetch their next work item. This would cancel the batch's processing, as cancellation was defined as halting the batch order (thus its individual ones, too). Anyway, queue gymnastics aren't simpler than your original (as warned), but I hoped it might trigger other ideas as you play with refactorings.

Comment: @BenManes thanks! I agree with general idea. but if you have a look at the step q_1 and q_2, you will see that Thread2 and Thread3 are two levels of consumers, it is not quite possible for Thread2, who will detect the poison pill, to find which of the Thread3 (each has one ItemOrder) this poison pill is for, without getting Thread2 to do step c_1, c_2, c_3 (which Thread4 is responsible of doing for right now). So the work may distributed differently between threads but complexity will not be reduced, I am afraid.

Comment: @BenManes, another potential problem with poison pill, comparing to the Shared State/Flag approach (which I know is universally hated) is that it may contradict with Requirement 2. As Thread2, who over-watches the queue, will now be forced to handle ItemOrders that are in front of the poison pill first, some of which are indeed meant to be cancelled by the effect of the very poison pill.

Comment: What you have is really the same as what `ThreadPoolExecutor` does, so you might use it instead? Flow A: submit all work, shutdown(), awaitTermination(). Flow B: Call shutdownNow() to exit flow A early.

Comment: @BenManes first of all, thank you, this provide me another angel to look at my design. 1. if we use the current design, there is a Queue of ItemOrders (Q1). and each Cancel request is to terminate (an imprecise word for this, as you will see in later points) only some of  ItemOrders in Q1. so ThreadPoolExecutor will not quite fit in here. 2. Now, if we get rid of Q1, i.e. if we let each Thread1 (for each BatchOrder) spawn a group of Thread3 (for each ItemOrder of that BatchOrder), then things get better. Naturally, we will use one ThreadPoolExecutor for each BatchOrder.

Comment: cont': that is, we will create a ThreadPoolExecutor in Thread1 at the point when we spawn the group of Thread3, ok? so far so good, right? 2.1 then the problem comes. because now after we spawn the group of Thread3, each of them will be responsible for

Comment: cont': steps [pb_4, pb_5, pi_1, pi_2] or just [pi_1, pi_2], depending how we want to design it. but either way, when we issue shutdown() to the ThreadPoolExecutor that spawned the group of Thread3, the Thread3 that has already started will continue until its end, which will contradict with Requirement2

Comment: `shutdownNow` should solve Requirement 2. Obviously spawning threads is inefficient, so your original design is correct for performance. The struggle, I believe, is wrapping the code in nice abstractions to keep it clean. You might be able to model it as an `ExecutorService` variant, one managed per batch and backed by a shared pool of threads. If successful, you would have a flow that feels more natural and the potential to reuse the component elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Assign class new attribute with enum type atomic, (as you do). Now when you push object to queue (it should be strong reference to the object) you also add it to cache (key - some identifier and value - another ref to the object). Now when you pop queue - in consumer you need to check this atomic attribute for the value and proceed if that is correct (not cancelled).in producer (processing batch order) if you need to remove value from processing you change this atomic attribute for canceled. This way you don't have to always check in consumers against itemOrder.